# Custom record reader for custom binary format

Tags: java, hadoop, binary-data, recordreader

In Hadoop v2 I need to create a `RecordReader` and/or an `InputFormat` based on some large binary formats stored in HDFS. The files are basically concatenated records with the following structure:

```
4-byte constant string "FOOO"
8-byte integer record length n1
n1-byte rest of the record

4-byte constant string "FOOO"
8-byte integer record length n2
n2-byte rest of the record

4-byte constant string "FOOO"
8-byte integer record length n3
n3-byte rest of the record

4-byte constant string "FOOO"
8-byte integer record length n4
n4-byte rest of the record
...
```

To know all of the boundary points, I'd therefore need to scan through the entire file.

Are there any examples of custom readers/formats that address structures like this?

I'm hoping to avoid pre-computing all the split points in advance, I'd rather stream in each record as the mapper needs it so I don't have to waste a loop through the data.  But even if I do have to pre-compute the split points, I don't know how to write a custom splitter so I'd appreciate a pointer to something like that too if possible.

One point to note: the "payload" of each record is essentially arbitrary binary data, and may contain the `"FOOO"` 4-byte constant in it as far as I know.  So if an input split falls somewhere in the middle of a record, I can't necessarily just advance to the next instance of `"FOOO"` to find the next record, nor would that be an efficient way to manage record-finding since it means scanning all the data rather than just the headers and seeking to the necessary locations.